# UIBezierPath Animation in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uibezierpath

I'm trying to make a animation that is done in Skype iOS application. The animation can be seen in this link [Animation Section 3:Add a Contact](http://blog.brianlovin.com/design-details-skype-for-ios/#3)

I tried with UIBezierPath but I can't do it. Any ideas?

Thanks!
My code

```
@implementation CustomView

#pragma mark - Lifecycle and initialize components


- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if ( self ) {

        self.alpha = 0;

        [self configureCancelButton];
        [self configureCollectionView];


        [self addSubview:self.cancelButton];
        [self addSubview:self.collectionView];


    }

    return self;
}

- (void) configureCancelButton {
    self.cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    [self.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector (cancelView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.8];
    self.cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7.f;

    self.frameForCancelButton = CGRectMake (self.bounds.origin.x+5, self.bounds.size.height - kCancelButtonHeight - 5, self.bounds.size.width-10, kCancelButtonHeight);

    self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake (self.frameForCancelButton.origin.x, self.frameForCancelButton.origin.y + kAnimationOffset, self.frameForCancelButton.size.width, self.frameForCancelButton.size.height);
}

- (void) configureCollectionView {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(kItemSize, kItemSize);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3.0;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 7, 10);
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

    self.frameForCollectionView = CGRectMake(self.cancelButton.frame.origin.x, self.frame.size.height -  (self.cancelButton.frame.size.height + 10 + kCollectionHeight), self.cancelButton.bounds.size.width, kCollectionHeight);

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (self.frameForCollectionView.origin.x, self.frameForCollectionView.origin.y + kAnimationOffset, self.frameForCollectionView.size.width, self.frameForCollectionView.size.height)
                                             collectionViewLayout:layout];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.8];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[RAShareCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.f;


}


#pragma mark - Public Methods


- (void) present {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        self.alpha = 1;
        self.darkView.alpha = .5;
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.45 options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [self setupAnimation];
    }                completion:nil];
}


- (void) cancelView {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake (self.frameForCancelButton.origin.x, self.frameForCancelButton.origin.y + kAnimationOffset, self.frameForCancelButton.size.width, self.frameForCancelButton.size.height);
        self.collectionView.frame= CGRectMake(self.frameForCollectionView.origin.x, self.frameForCollectionView.origin.y + kAnimationOffset, self.frameForCollectionView.size.width, self.frameForCollectionView.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }];
    ;
}

- (void) setupAnimation {
    self.cancelButton.alpha = 1;
    self.collectionView.alpha = 1;

    self.cancelButton.frame = self.frameForCancelButton;
    self.collectionView.frame = self.frameForCollectionView;

    [self addShapeLayer];

}

- (void)addShapeLayer
{
    self.shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.shapeLayer.path = [[self pathAtInterval:0.0] CGPath];
    self.shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.collectionView.layer insertSublayer:self.shapeLayer atIndex:0];

}

- (UIBezierPath *) pathAtInterval:(NSTimeInterval) interval {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.frame.origin.x,self.collectionView.frame.origin.y)];

    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.origin.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2, self.collectionView.frame.origin.y-30)];


    return path;
}
```

Comment: Use `UIBezierPath`. If you show your code and ask a question about a specific problem you're experiencing, someone may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your animation block does not contain any animations. You should move your setup outside of the animation block and then animate within it.

```
[self setupAnimation];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.45 options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    // animate something
}                completion:nil];
```

In addition to this, your intended animation does not have a linear progression, meaning that you'l want to use `animateKeyframesWithDuration` instead.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.45 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:i/10.0
                            relativeDuration:1.0/10.0
                                  animations:^{
                                      self.shapeLayer = [self pathAtInterval:i/10.0];
                                  }];
  }
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

1, add the path you created to CAShaperLayer object; 
2, see the "strokeStart" and "strokeEnd" properties in CAShapeLayer class;
3, add a animation which called "CABasicAnimation" to your Layer obj.